# Proof of the Collection Principle (Jech, 3rd Edition, (6.5))

Tags: set-theory

This question is about the proof of the Collection Schema (6.5) in Jech's Set Theory, 3rd Edition:

> $\forall X \exists Y \, (\forall u \in X) [\exists v \varphi(u, v, p) \implies (\exists v \in Y) \varphi(u, v, p)]$

I understand that Jech's set

\begin{equation}
  Y \triangleq \cup_{u \in X} \hat{C}_u, \quad C_u \triangleq \{v: \varphi(u, v, p)\}
\end{equation}

will do, but I don't quite see why $Y$ is a set. Certainly, as Jech continues to state,

\begin{equation}
  v \in Y \Leftrightarrow (\forall u \in X) (\varphi(u, v, p) \text{ and } \forall{z} (\varphi(u, z, p) \implies \text{rank}(v) \leq \text{rank}(z)),
\end{equation}

which is very reminiscent of the statement of the Replacement Schema, but I don't quite see how to apply it. More precisely, I believe it would suffice to prove that

\begin{equation}
  \psi(u, v, p) \triangleq \varphi(u, v, p) \text{ and } \forall{z} (\varphi(u, z, p) \implies \text{rank}(v) \leq \text{rank}(z))
\end{equation}

satisfies

\begin{equation}
  \psi(u, v, p) \text{ and } \psi(u, w, p) \implies v = w,
\end{equation}

but I don't know how. By the rank condition we certainly must have

\begin{equation}
  \text{rank}(v) = \text{rank}(w) \implies v \notin w \text{ and } w \notin v
\end{equation}

but that doesn't lead to the desired conclusion. Hence my question: Am I on the right track, and if so, how do I wrap this up, and if not, how do I show that $Y$ is a set?

Comment: What you have written seems incomplete. Shouldn't $C_u$ consist solely of those $v$ in the current $C_u$ that are of minimal rank? (Particularly, if you want the next displayed line to be true.)

Comment: If you are just copying what Jech wrote, then he made a typo and his definition of $C_u$ should be modified as I suggest.

Comment: What you are trying to prove about $\psi$ is false, by the way. But unnecessary.

Comment: Jech defines $\hat{C}$ as the set of minimal-rank members of $C$, hence I have $\hat{C}_u$ and $C_u$ appearing. I guess this notation is not as common as I thought. Regarding $\psi$: I didn't really believe it to be true, but I don't quite see how else to apply Replacement. Could you please point me to the right idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y=\bigcup_{u\in X}\hat{C}_u=\bigcup\{\hat{C}_u:u\in X\}$. Now we need a set $A$ conataining those $\hat{C}_u$ so that $Y=\bigcup\{\hat{C}_u\in A:u\in X\}$ is a set. But such $A$ exists by the class function $u\mapsto \hat{C}_u$ and Replacement Axiom.